# Shading Java jar - Xerces issue

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, xerces

I am running a Hadoop Mapreduce job. The `xerces` i am using and the Hadoop distribution looks different. I want to shade my `xerces`. How would I do it?

Doing this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                 <artifactSet>
                     <excludes>
                         <exclude>xerces:xercesImpl:jar:</exclude>
                     </excludes>
                 </artifactSet>
                 <relocations>
                     <relocation>
                         <pattern>org.apache.xerces.impl.*</pattern>
                             <shadedPattern>org.shaded.xerces.impl.*</shadedPattern>
                     </relocation>
                 </relocations>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Is giving this error. Googling around didn't help much:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (default) on project dsl-mapreduce: Error creating shaded jar: Error in ASM processing class com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class: 48188 -> [Help 1]
```

I am not using `com/ibm/icu/impl` anywhere and `icu` or `icu4j` doesn't exist in the `mvn dependency:tree` as well.

EDIT: The jar is compiled on Java 8 and Hadoop is on Java 7.

Comment: Check via `mvn dependency:tree`  cause it should be a transitive dependency.

Comment: Its not there in `mvn dependency:tree`. I already mentioned in the question.